# Debian 7.7 PPC (iMac G4) - switch from nouveau to nv driver

Tags: debian, nvidia, macintosh, nouveau

I'm trying to get some flavour of Linux going on an old iMac G4/800 with NV11 video hardware. So far I've tried Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 12.04 and Debian 7.7. All face the following common issues:

- I cannot get nouveau to work - at all. The console gets rendered OK, but once nouveau is initialized, the screen 'fades to white' and I get a hard lockup - no Ctrl-Alt switches, no blind command-line stuff, nothing. This applies to both the 'current' nouveau included with the above distributions and the latest-released nouveau 1.0.11 (which I installed manually.)
- I can boot to command line if I don't load nouveau (i.e. use nomodeset or nouveau.modeset = 0 as yaboot parameters).
- fbdev and vesafb give a low-colour utterly unusable desktop.
- The old Mac OS X 10.2 that was on the machine worked flawlessly so I don't think there's a hardware problem.

Focusing on Debian 7.7:

- There is a package for 'xserver-xorg-video-nv' in the /oldstable archives.

EDIT: I can't install the xserver-xorg-video-nv package from oldstable without a lot of risk, as it seems that there are conflicts with the newer xserver-xorg-core / xserver-video-abi-6.0 which is installed. So - is there a way to get nouveau working with NV11, or is there a known-good way to get vesafb going on this card to present a useable desktop?

EDIT #2: vesafb doesn't seem to work, as fbdev seems to be misidentifying the hardware. I try passing 'video=vesafb:1024x768-16@60' and end up with a psychedelic low-color mouse pointer and this in the Xorg.0.log:

```
(==) FBDEV(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section "Default Screen Section" section for depth/fbbpp 8
(==) FBDEV(0): Depth = 8, (==) framebuffer bpp 8
(==) FBDEV(0): Default visual is PseudoColor
(==) FBDEV(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
(==) FBDEV(0): hardware: 0Ffb NVDA,NVMAC (video memory: 768kb)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current solution, for the record:

The only way I was able to get the display going on this machine was:

- blacklist `nouveau`
- add the `oldstable` repositories to `sources.list`
- `apt-get remove` the entire Xorg subsystem (and gdm)
- `apt-get -t oldstable install` the previous revision's Xorg subsystem (including the nv driver) and xfce4

(I opted to go with xfce4 given the age of the hardware)

[image: iMac G4 running Debian 7.7 and xfce4]

X starts up, loads the nv driver and ... now I have a GUI.

It's a bit of a compromise but at least parts of the operating system are up-to-date.

Answer (score -2):

There is a way to install proprietary drivers that supposed to work better: 
Go http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us.
In **Product Type** select **Legacy**.
In **Product Series** select **GeForce 2 MX Series**
Click **Search**
Download `*.run` file. 
Set executable options for it `chmod +x *.run`
Run it.

Comment: Proprietary drivers are not provided for PowerPC. I'm using an iMac G4. I have had good success with them on Intel PCs though.

Comment: I had same problems with one my "new" nvidia video hardware. So, any nouveau solution gave me only fbdev ( just like in your case ) but X11 gave me only white screen ( just like yours ). And my solution was installing proprietary drivers. So, could you please explain why you can't install those drivers on your PowerPC?

Comment: The proprietary drivers rely on a binary blob which is only compiled for x86 architectures.

Comment: The webpage you cited confirms what I already knew - only x86 and x64 drivers are provided by nVidia. No powerpc.

Comment: Okay, this way I assume this link may be useful for You https://packages.debian.org/search?arch=powerpc&searchon=sourcenames&keywords=nvidia-graphics-drivers

Comment: Um, how? Even "source" shows only amd64 and x86 packages.

Comment: I just say what I see http://s10.postimg.org/i2vhfkhp5/blah.png . You could try binaries.

Comment: Appreciate the effort but clearly you misunderstand. nVidia has *never* released a driver for PowerPC - binary or source. Other than generic drivers like veasfb, there are exactly two choices for PowerPC - nouveau and nv. That's all.